# How to design java api to communicate with two different server

Tags: java, api

I have to create java api which will talk with two different server one for licensing and after getting token from licensing server it will talk with another server .

I need help to figure out efficient way to create model object which will hold json request response for both server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a maven project with 4 module(api, persistence,service,rest) and use javaee coding

Comment: Should I use one pojo or two pojo class to communicate with two different server ?

Comment: I think you can use 1 pojo

Comment: how i will manage request response with different attribute in one pojo?

Comment: with a restapi class